# Use Spark 2.2.0 to read from Hive metastore 2.x

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, metastore

Prior to version 2.2.0 Spark was unable to communicate to Hive 2.X so I was stuck using Hive 1 + Spark 1/2. For what I have read in both:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18112
https://spark.apache.org/releases/spark-release-2-2-0.html

It is now possible to use Spark 2 + Hive 2 but I'm still facing some issues. Using the pre-compiled Spark-without-hadoop, I get the following error when accessing a temporal hive table:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to instantiate SparkSession with Hive support because Hive classes are not found.
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.enableHiveSupport(SparkSession.scala:845)
>       at io.bigdatabenchmark.v2.queries.q05.LogisticRegression$.main(LogisticRegression.scala:87)
>       at io.bigdatabenchmark.v2.queries.q05.LogisticRegression.main(LogisticRegression.scala)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:755)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:119)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

I normally solve this issue by compiling my own version of Spark with the options "-Phive -Phive-thriftserver" but by default Spark will build with Hive 1.2.1 bindings as seen in the documentation.

So, as it seems Spark 2.2.0 solves the issue of Spark 2 -> Hive 2 binding but I can't find a proper way to compile it so it can access a metastore with schema 2.x.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Add following dependency to your maven project.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-hive_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I'm not being able to finish the compilation when adding the new dependency in the pom.xml both in the general folder (/spark-2.2.0/pom.xml) and in the sql project (/spark-2.2.0/sql/hive/pom.xml). In both tests I receive the following error:

`[error] /home/alejandro/Documents/projects/spark/spark-2.2.0/sql/hive/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/hive/HiveStrategies.scala:165: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.CatalogTable
[error]  required: org.apache.spark.sql.hive.MetastoreRelation`

Comment: I've updated the dependency in my answer. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: This time around the compilation finishes successfully but when trying to read from metastore I get: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to instantiate SparkSession with Hive support because Hive classes are not found.`

Probably I'm putting the dependency where it does not belong.

Comment: are you using spark-submit ?

Comment: Yep alongside a bunch of jars.